# Query on BCS list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, development, bcs

I need to retrieve the items of BCS based list.
I am using the server side object model on SP2013 and I am getting this error:

> An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: The shim execution failed unexpectedly – Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089′ or one of its dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not
>   provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)

I am running this code from a console application:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysiteUrl"))
{
    var context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
    using (var scope = new SPServiceContextScope(context))
    {
        SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
        using (web)
        {
            SPList myList = web.Lists["BCS List"];
            var items = (from SPListItem item in myList.Items
                     where Convert.ToString(item["MyField"]) == "myValue"
                           select item).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is on the *.Items* attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I solved running the console application with **Administrator privileges**.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to your solution based on running the program under admin account, you can give a try to using impersonation in SP code. Hope these links would be useful for you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/03/13/using-spsite-and-spweb-objects-with-runwithelevatedprivileges-don-t-cross-the-borders.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436101

Comment: I tried also to use it, but it did not help. I think that the problem was to load some DDLs that is why run shell as admin solved the problem.